# Get available memory MIFARE DESFire EV1

Tags: smartcard, rfid, mifare, apdu, contactless-smartcard

How can I get the available memory of a MIFARE DESFire EV1 card? I know some Android applications show the available memory. So is there any APDU command to get the available memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the total memory size using the GetVersion command:

```
<-- 90 60 0000 00
--> ZZ YY XX WW VV TT SS 91AF
<-- 90 AF 0000 00
--> ZZ YY XX WW VV TT SS 91AF
<-- 90 AF 0000 00
--> UUUUUUUUUUUUUU NNNNNNNNNN WW YY 9100
```

Where SS is the storage size and can be decoded as

```
int storageBytes = 1 << ((int)SS & 0x0FE) >>> 1);
bool storageExact = ((int)SS & 0x01) != 0;
```

The lowest bit indicates if the indicated storage size (in bytes) is an exact value or if the actual storage size is between `storageBytes` and `storageBytes * 2`.

You can also get the available free memory (in bytes) using the FreeMem command:

```
<-- 90 6E 0000 00
--> SSSSSS 9100
```

Comment: Thanks! Where did you get this information? Is there a list of desfire commands? I have been searching for hours...